# AFJSONRequestOperation Progress shown on UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, afnetworking

Given the following code, say I connect to a service and fetch some items, I need to update a label to show the progress while the items are "processed"

The problem is the operation blocks the main thread and the UILabel only gets update after it iterates all the items.

How can I fix this code so it will get updated every time?

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = 
[AFJSONRequestOperationJSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
   datas = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
   for(int i = 0; i < [datas count]; i ++)
   {
       //do stuff with the item

       NSMutableString *progressText = [[NSMutableString alloc] 
            initWithFormat:@"Done with %d out of  %@ items", i, [datas count]];
       self.progressLabel.text = progressText;
   }
 }];

 [operation start]
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of http request for json data will get response only once, and you can get all the data in the "JSON" object. So there is no need to show progress. Only in case that a request will receive multiple responses , you need to show the progress .For example ,a request for a webview.